# javascript code prime numbers wont show

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am studying JavaScript and right now is Im trying to show the prime numbers. but unfortunately it doesnt display. can someone help Iam stuck with these.

This is my code:

```
function getPrimes(max) {
var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
 if (!sieve[i]) {
      primes.push(i);
        for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
            sieve[j] = true;
        }
    }
}
return primes;
}
getPrimes(10);
```

---

and also I tried this. but still nothing shows.
second code:

```
function findeprime(num){
 var isPrime;
 for (var i = 2; i < num; i++){
         isPrime = true;
         for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
         if (i % coun == 0) isPrime = false;
         }
    if (isPrime) document.write(i + " is prime <br/>");
    }
}
finderprime(5);
```

Comment: Typo...finderprime or findeprime

Comment: The first example works you're just not printing it out. The second example there is a typo between finderprime and findeprime.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "doesn't display"? This code works fine for me in a console. You just don't have any code to actually output or display the returned values.

If you're trying to output to the console, try using `console.log()`.

If you're trying to make this appear on a webpage, try out `document.write();`.

Comment: Hello thank you! sorry, Im so noob. by the way. I have change return to doument.write();. but I am confuse for what does "return do?, does it make sense?

Comment: `return` will stop the execution of function and will return the value of the function. it will not print the value. just return the value. you can refer here: [ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp ]

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st code you have not printed variable **primes**

```
function getPrimes(max) {
var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
 if (!sieve[i]) {
      primes.push(i);
        for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
            sieve[j] = true;


        }
    }

}
       document.writeln(primes);
}
getPrimes(10);
```

For the 2nd code, You have given different names to the same function.

```
function findprime(num){
 var isPrime;
 for (var i = 2; i < num; i++){
         isPrime = true;
         for (coun = 2; coun < i; coun++) {
         if (i % coun == 0) isPrime = false;
         }
    if (isPrime) document.write(i + " is prime <br/>");
    }
}

var number = 5;
findprime(number);
```

Comment: Hello Bavin, Thanks for your help. Im so noob! :)